# Git user.name continuously removed/reset

Tags: git

At least once a day it seems that my Git global configuration value for `user.name` gets reset to a blank value. Of course I only find out when I go to commit and it barks at me. I've tried removing and readding, replacing all matching keys. Here are the following specs/configs I would think are relevant:

- MacBook Pro 15,1 (2018)
- macOS 11.1
- iTerm2 v3.4.3
- Git v2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)

I also have Oh My Zsh installed, master commit SHA `b28665a`.

Comment: Where have you set the username?

Comment: I had set the `user.name` and `user.email` with the command and `--global` flag. I also had configured those properties per project as well, but all projects would eventually (and daily) ignore the local and global settings. I also tried using the `--system` flag when setting it, but that wasn't the fix.

Comment: What was the  command?

Comment: `git config --global user.name "<name>"`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by manually removing the entry for `"credential.helper=osxkeychain"` in my global config file.